# How to implement a overlapping Background Design in React

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm new to React and wanted to ask what's the cleanest way to implement a background design like this. I want to know how you could change the background to blue and have the images overlap into the white area or the rings in the corners. So what is the best approach? And I don't want to use a background image

[Background I want to implement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msXXN.png)

Comment: It is not necessary to use react at all for this use case. Would also be possible with plain css. Could you please provide a more specific example?

Comment: Yes, sure in my case I'm just using react. My main question is how I could implement the Background illustrations without a picture so I can Have Content over it. Like a Picture over the blue and white area.

Comment: you could try to search for react and svg e.g.: [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/cpw5j) or [how-to-use-svgs-in-react](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-svgs-in-react/)

Answer (score 0):

```
  position: fixed;
  background: "your image or some colors";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
```

Other contents should appear accordingly if you apply proper z-index

Answer (score 0):

There are several options.

1. You can add !important behind the code that wnna be overwrite.
2. add z-index for the each element. note : the higher z-index number of the element, it will be place at the top.
3. in-line style. where you can add tag style={{ your style here}} within your element. example

   ```
   <div style={{z-index : 10, backgroundImage : black}} > Text here </div>
   ```
4. manual CSS with tag backgroud-image.